# Generated Report loses some elements in printing

Tags: html, css, printing

My company utilizes a software system that can generate reports and export them to a variety of formats.  One of the formats is HTML and it does indeed look nice and keep the fidelity of the reports.  However, when I go to print the report some of the elements on the page don't get printed.  They are mostly stylistic things like lines that act as borders between areas.  They are there when viewed in Chrome or Firefox, but immediately disappear when you go to print.

Everything is made with inline css styling such as:

```
<div style="page-break-inside:avoid;page-break-after:always;">
```

```
<span style="position:absolute;top:0.09388888in;left:0.7161965in;width:6.658803in;height:0.2861111in;font-family:Arial;font-size:14pt;color:Black;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top;background-color:#FFFFFF;"><nobr>Report</nobr></span>
```

Here is a fiddle of the report so you can see what I'm talking about:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/otictac1/60pahz8e/
```

The yellow bar doesn't print nor do the borders that surround the table looking thing on the right.

Any thoughts on what might be causing that?

Comment: while printing, browser by default disable background graphics. you can enable them in your browser while printing. in chrome you will find the option under more settings -> option

Comment: YES!  Thank you so much!  That was it!